# Will Java's synchronization update the complete cache, or only the object I synchronized on?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, parallel-processing, monitor

If I access an object inside of a synchronized method or synchronized block, are all object in that accessed element also synchronized?

Imagine there's an object `Queue` having a synchronized `add()` and `take()` method, accepting and handing out the complex object `Thing`. `Thing` has a lot of lists with other different objects in it.

Now image thread `Before` creates `Thing` and puts some existing objects into `Thing`, modifies some of these object and so on. The `Before` thread adds `Thing` to `Queue`. A bit later thread `After` takes the `Thing` from `Queue`.

QUESTION: Will `Thing` and all its children/subobject be in the same state as `Before` left them in? Even if thread `After` was maybe working on one of these subelements a bit earlier? Because I image the processor for thread `After` might still have some cached information on that subelement (the address of that subobject is still the same). All this cached stuff would be invalidated only through accessing the father object `Thing` in a synchronized way?

Please don't give answers like use the concurrency libs etc. I want to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The important concept in Java's memory model is the [*happens-before* order](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5). Results of write actions which *happen-before* read actions are visible to these read actions. Other results may or may not be visible.

The *happen-before* order is induced by synchronization order of actions between threads, and by the *natural* order of actions in the individual threads.

If you in `Before` synchronize on an object (e.g. your `Queue`), and do all of your manipulations of `Thing` and its "subobjects" inside or before this synchronized-block, and `After` synchronized on the same `Queue` and reads these objects in or after the synchronized-block, then *all those changes* are visible to `After`.

Answer (score 9):

If a thread modifies a variable, another thread is not guaranteed to see the changes except in the following cases (well, at least in the following cases; I'm not 100% sure if there are more):

- the modifying thread leaves a synchronized block or method; this induces a flush of the thread cache (likewise a thread that enters a synchronized block or method induces a refresh) -- this is what happens in your case
- the modified variable is declared `volatile` or it is one of the atomic variables from `java.util.concurrent.atomic`
- the modifying thread finishes (this also induces a flush, likewise the start of a thread induces a refresh)

So if you synchronize as you explained, other threads will see all changes.

Comment: yes I know that, but that was not quite my question :-) Synchronization must also affect processor caches, so that changes are flushed to common memory, that is what my question is about. I know that if you access a reference without going through a synchronized block from mulitple parallel threads it gets everything messed up. But this is more about passing stuff from one thread to another and ensuring that the datastrucuture is still correct. Understand what I mean?

Comment: See the answer by Paulo.  Blocking threads is only one aspect of synchronization, the happens-before relationship (flushing the cache) is as important if not more.  It is also a lot trickier to understand and the API's are unclear about happens-before (for example, I think that SwingUtilities.invokeLater provokes an happens-before, but I'm not 100% sure).  I strongly recommend Java Concurrency in Practice from Goetz et al.  They put a lot of emphasis on happens-before.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without explanation... @Franz: It was not apparent to me that you were asking about the memory model. Let me reconsider my answer.

Comment: @toto2: Fair enough. The question really sounded like something different to me. I hope I got it now. :)